# How to encrypt Erlang rpc calls (and Mnesia replication) and other traffic?

Tags: security, encryption, erlang

I believe that internode communication is taking place in the clear and that the cookie value is strictly used for authentication. (I do not have any proof as yet).

1. How do I encrypt internode communication?
2. How do I encrypt Mnesia replication messages?
3. How do I configure my firewall and packet filters to permit these messages to pass through?
4. How do I prevent snooping of my Erlang traffic?

Comment: Might help to condense those questions a little bit :)

Comment: I would agree except they are related and I really hated the idea of writing 4 separate questions since they seemed to close.

Comment: I think that all four together here makes perfect sense; the answers to these questions are interrelated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since it all runs over IP, one option would be to use IPSec between your nodes. Encrypted VPN connections could also do the trick. Neither of these require any changes on the Erlang side of things, nor will the Erlang programs or runtime be aware that the encryption is happening, except in the (hopefully) rare case of attacks that cause communication to fail, in which case it will look as if the other node is down.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure that there is a trivial solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this answer because; it makes sense and it seems to be the strongest. Considering the "unix way" this eliminates having to add code to the erlang implementation. Making it more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an SSH tunnel to pass all erlang communications through it, using the -rsh ssh parameter, you will want to set up certificate-based authentication for ssh (i.e. no passwords). Then you can simply use something along the lines of

> erl -rsh ssh ....

For additional details, please see:

- [Pooling and Automated Code Distribution with Erlang](http://pentaphase.de/index.php?/archives/30-Pooling-and-Automated-Code-Distribution-with-Erlang.html)
- [Starting a set of Erlang cluster nodes with SSH](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/ERL/Starting+a+set+of+Erlang+cluster+nodes)

Comment: As far as "stunnel" is concerned... in order to be effective one needs to know which ports erlang is going to use. I have not been able to identify that... and in fact it has been said that they are hare to nail down.

I read the rest of your answer and followed the links. While this is a cool feature... and yet poorly documented... it does not address my question which is about RPC.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible out of the box with the use of the `inet_tls_dist` custom distribution module. There is a [guide in the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html) on how to use `inet_tls_dist` module as the distribution module to get encrypted communications between cluster nodes. I'm not sure when all these features where introduced, but I know they are present in Erlang 18.2 and newer.

Erlang Solutions also wrote a [blog post on this](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/erlang-distribution-over-tls.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options:

1. Use **SSL to connect the Erlang nodes** as described [on Trap Exit](http://www.trapexit.org/Distributed_erlang_using_ssl_through_firewalls)
2. Use **underlaying IP mechanisms** like VPN or IpSEC

Comment: -1 old; The trapexit article was written in 2007 and the author hopes for inclusion of some patches he made. Apparently SSL is an option (I do not see where yet), however, one cannot control the port as he said.